# How to show AdMob Non-Personalized Native Advanced ads in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads, native-ads

I tried various different methods but none of them seem to work.
This is given by AdMob:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("npa", "1");

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
    .build();
```

The code I use:

```
AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, "ca-app-pub-XXXXX").forNativeAd(new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNativeAdLoaded(@NonNull NativeAd nativeAds) {
                if (nativeAds!=null) nativeAd = nativeAds;
                CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.adCard);
                NativeAdView adView = (NativeAdView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.native_ad_view, null);
                populateNativeAd(nativeAd, adView);
                cardView.removeAllViews();
                cardView.addView(adView);
            }
        });
```

The ads are loaded and shown without the usage of `AdRequest` and I can't find a way forward consent using AdLoader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is facing the same confusion:
`AdRequest` is used in this line:

`adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());`

My bad. The code was too long and I was not able to find this line.
Change it to:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("npa", "1");
adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras).build());
```